# Plotly: How to plot Horizontal line Between "2 Points" where points on x axis are Months

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

Is there a way to control the starting and ending points of horizontal and vertical lines in `plotly`?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
        
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter())
fig.add_vline(x=1, line_width=2, line_dash="dash", line_color="green")
fig.add_hline(y=2, line_width=2, line_dash="dash", line_color="red")
fig.show()
```

Code above will plot lines but on whole screen

I want to do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,7))

ax.hlines(y=2, xmin='July', xmax='Aug', linewidth=2, color='red', linestyles = 'dotted')
ax.axvline(x = 1,color = 'green', linestyle = 'dotted', linewidth = 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/), `add_vline` will span the entire y-axis of the plot, and `add_hline` will span the entire x-axis of the plot.

You can instead use the `add_shape` method for figures from Plotly [Shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#vertical-and-horizontal-lines-positioned-relative-to-the-axis-data) and add a line segment by specifying the start and end coordinates using the arguments `x0`,`x1`,`y0`,`y1`.

EDIT: if you have datetimes on your x-axis, you can pass datetimes to the x-coordinate arguments

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="GOOG")

vertical_date_time = pd.to_datetime("2018-07-01")
horizontal_date_time_start = pd.to_datetime("2018-04-01")
horizontal_date_time_end = pd.to_datetime("2018-10-01")
fig.add_shape(type="line", x0=vertical_date_time, y0=0.9, x1=vertical_date_time, y1=1.2, line_width=2, line_dash="dash", line_color="green")
fig.add_shape(type="line", x0=horizontal_date_time_start, y0=1.05, x1=horizontal_date_time_end, y1=1.05, line_width=2, line_dash="dash", line_color="red")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But I have x-axis as the name of Months, years, seconds etc. that's the problem

Comment: @Deshwal I updated my answer using some sample data with a datetime xaxis

Comment: Just one more help if you can, by default it shows gaps in non trading days. For `Day`, I have made some adjustments but for minute data, it is still showing some gaps. Any idea?

Comment: @Deshwal I would be happy to help, but i think what you are asking is outside of the original question here. can you create a new question regarding gaps in data?

Comment: Sure, had already put [this question. Can you please answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716384/ignore-non-trading-days-holidays-remove-gaps-in-plotly-candlesticks-for-min)