Removing Weekends from Historical Stock Data from Oanda API
I'm pretty new to programming and I am learning to code a backtest with data from Oanda API. When I plot the chart below, I get these gaps on weekends. I check the data and index(time) does not show the weekends yet it shows up on the chart. How can I get rid of it? Much appreciate your time!

This is my code:
class Backtester():
    def __init__(self, symbol, timeframe, SMA_S, SMA_L, start, end):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.timeframe = timeframe
        self.SMA_S = SMA_S
        self.SMA_L = SMA_L
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.results = None
        self.get_data()

    def get_data(self):
        api = tpqoa.tpqoa('oanda.cfg')
        raw = api.get_history(instrument = self.symbol, \
                              start = self.start, \
                              end = self.end, \
                              granularity = self.timeframe, \
                              price = 'B')
        # raw = raw.dropna(inplace =True)
        # raw.rename(column = {'c':'close'})
        raw['returns'] = np.log(raw['c'] / raw['c'].shift(1))
        raw['SMA_S'] = raw['c'].rolling(self.SMA_S).mean()
        raw['SMA_L'] = raw['c'].rolling(self.SMA_L).mean()
        raw.dropna(inplace = True)
        self.data = raw
        return raw

    def test_strategy(self):
        data = self.data.copy().dropna()
        data["position"] = np.where(data["SMA_S"] > data["SMA_L"], 1, -1)
        data["strategy"] = data["position"].shift(1) * data["returns"]
        data.dropna(inplace=True)
        data["creturns"] = data["returns"].cumsum().apply(np.exp)
        data["cstrategy"] = data["strategy"].cumsum().apply(np.exp)
        self.results = data
        
        perf = data["cstrategy"].iloc[-1] # absolute performance
        outperf = perf - data["creturns"].iloc[-1] # outperformance 
        return round(perf, 6), round(outperf, 6)

    def plot_data(self):
        data = self.data.copy().dropna()

        candle = go.Candlestick(x = data.index,\
                                open = data['o'],\
                                close = data['c'],\
                                high = data['h'],\
                                low = data['l'],
                                name = 'Candlestick')
        fsma = go.Scatter(x = data.index,\
                          y = data['SMA_S'],\
                          name = 'SMA Short',\
                          line = dict(color = ('rgba(102, 207, 255, 50)')))
        lsma = go.Scatter(x = data.index,\
                          y = data['SMA_L'],\
                          name = 'SMA Long',\
                          line = dict(color = ('rgba(102, 107, 255, 50)')))

        data = [candle, fsma, lsma]
        data = [candle]
        layout = go.Layout(title = self.symbol)
        fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
        plot(fig, filename = self.symbol)


https://stackoverflow.com/q/70716384/26993270

See this reference for more information
