# Can I add a vline and hline to a plotly plot ignoring marginal plots?

Tags: python, plotly, data-science, data-visualization

I am moving a visualization from the seaborn library to the plotly library.
I want a scatterplot with marginal histograms for my x and y variables.
I want to show a vertical and horizontal line for the average of my x and y variables.

To show my problem I created a dummy dataframe of random X and Y values

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('XY'))
```

I want to replicate the seaborn library output on plotly.

```py
g = sns.JointGrid(data=df, x="X", y="Y")
g.plot(sns.scatterplot, sns.histplot)
g.refline(x=df.X.mean(), y=df.Y.mean())

plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn plot]

When I do something similar on plotly using `add_line` and `add_hline` I get the following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('XY'))
fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y',
                marginal_y="histogram", marginal_x="histogram",
                width=800, height=600)
fig.add_hline(y=df['X'].mean(), line_dash='dash', annotation_text= f"{df['X'].mean():.0f}")
fig.add_vline(x=df['Y'].mean(), line_dash='dash', annotation_text=f"{df['Y'].mean():.0f}")

fig.show()
```

[image: plotly plot]

My issue is that the horizontal line is plotted also plotted on the marginal x plot and the vertical line is also plotted on the marginal y plot. Is there a way to prevent the horizontal line to be plotted on the marginal x plot and the vertical line to be plotted on the marginal y plot?

Comment: I want to replicate the Seabron approach on plotly. Not the other way around. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to plot Horizontal line Between "2 Points" where points on x axis are Months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714620/plotly-how-to-plot-horizontal-line-between-2-points-where-points-on-x-axis-ar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define row and column of the panel grid when plotting hline/vline:

```
fig.add_hline(y=df['X'].mean(), line_dash='dash', row=1, annotation_text= f"{df['X'].mean():.0f}")
fig.add_vline(x=df['Y'].mean(), line_dash='dash', col=1, annotation_text=f"{df['Y'].mean():.0f}")
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: This solved my question. Thank you so much!